# How to find the position/index of a particular file in a directory?

Tags: python

I am new to python.I have a list of file names contained in a folder and I want to build a function which can search and return the position of a particular file in the list of files.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far ?

Comment: def find(name, path):
    count=0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            count+=1
    print count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you have a list of string `list_of_names=["Abc","Def","Ghi","Jkl"]`.

You can use list.index() method to find the index of a particular string as given below:

```
>> list_of_names.index("Abc")
>> 0
>> list_of_names.index("Jkl")
>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

please do this

```
names = [filename1,filename2,.............]
index = names.index(filename you want to search) 
print index
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. Assuming you wanted the files alphabetical.

```
>>> from os import listdir
>>> my_files = listdir('./')
>>> my_files.sort()
>>> my_files.index('myfile.txt')
9
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
  os.listdir(path).index('filename')
```