# Revisit "How to find the position/index of a particular file in a directory?"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a question from the following discussion:

[How to find the position/index of a particular file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675412/how-to-find-the-position-index-of-a-particular-file-in-a-directory)

Suppose I have *three excel files* in a folder: *test_3d, test_3d1, test_3d2*

It says we can read the **index of a file** from the following codes

```
folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\test_read'
files = os.listdir(folder)
files.index('test_3d1.xlsx')

>> 1
```

Also, we can read the **data of each file** by

```
folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\test_read'
files = os.listdir(folder)
dfs = {}
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        dfs[file[:-5]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")

dfs['test_3d1']
```

[image]

Also, we can show all its files by using

```
files
>> ['test_3d.xlsx', 'test_3d1.xlsx', 'test_3d2.xlsx']
```

My question now is how to get the data of each file **not** by its name

```
dfs['test_3d1']
```

but by its **index**, for example

```
dfs['files[1]']   # I want to pick up the 2nd file 'text_3d1' from files.
```

However, it shows an error

[image]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the object types you are working with, in this piece of code:

```
folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\test_read'
files = os.listdir(folder)
dfs = {}
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        dfs[file[:-5]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")

dfs['test_3d1']
```

Notice that `dfs` is a dictionary, so we accessed the file by it's `key`, and here we defined the `key` as the file of the name.

If you wish to change that into it's index then store it as such like so:

```
folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\test_read'
files = os.listdir(folder)
dfs = {}
# Here is the change
for i,file in enumerate(files):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        dfs[i] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to look values in the dictionary as per the screenshot you posted, you could do: `dfs[files[1][:-5]]`. This gets the file at index 1 and then excludes the file extension as you've done in in the step to build the `dfs` dictionary.

Optionally, you could use the [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) available for dictionaries to change the behaviour of how keys which aren't present in the dictionary are handled. Using the [recipe from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6229253/1431750), you could use a lookup on the [dictionary `values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) or modify the key to remove the file extension and then return the value for that key. So you can use it with `dfs[files[1]]` without needing to strip off the extension each time.

```py
In [1]: class smart_dict(dict):
   ...:     def __missing__(self, key):
   ...:         if isinstance(key, int):             # skip this if you don't plan
   ...:             return list(self.values())[key]  # to use ints directly
   ...:             # or
   ...:             # return self[list(self.keys())[key]]
   ...:         if key.endswith('.xlsx'):
   ...:             return self[key[:-5]]
   ...:         raise KeyError(key)
   ...:

In [2]: dfs = smart_dict()
   ...: dfs['a'] = 'A'
   ...: dfs['b'] = 'B'

In [3]: dfs['a']  # normal usage
Out[3]: 'A'

In [4]: dfs[0]  # index-based lookup
Out[4]: 'A'

In [5]: dfs[1]
Out[5]: 'B'

In [6]: dfs['a.xlsx']  # lookup with the filename
Out[6]: 'A'

In [7]: dfs['does not exist']  # still raises KeyError
...
KeyError: 'does not exist'

In [8]:  dfs['nope.xlsx']  # also raises KeyError
...
KeyError: 'nope'
```

Btw, there is an overhead to constantly doing `list(dict.values())[index]`  lookups for integer keys since `values()` can't indexed directly. So avoid using that. The '.xlsx' extension-removal lookup is okay since it merely removes the extension and then directly uses that as a key.